# How to create a button to toggle superscript input

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently creating a javascript calculator and I want to create a toggle button for superscript functionality. When button is toggled on, any button that the user presses will appear in superscript form. Once button is toggled off, user input will go back to normal.

Currently I have the calculator HTML format in place, with all the buttons that can be clicked to insert numbers. The button with attribute 'data-powers' is the button that I wish to implement this superscript toggle functionality on.

Html code:

```
        <div class="form-group">
           <div data-current-content contenteditable="true" class="form-control form-control-lg" style="min-height: 50px;">
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container mx-0">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="calculator-grid">
                        <button data-append type="button"><i>x</i></button>
                        <button data-append type="button"><i>y</i></button>
                        <button data-power2 type="button">a<sup>2</sup></button>
                        <button data-powers class="button" type="button">a<sup>b</sup></button>
                        <button data-append type="button">(</button>
                        <button data-append type="button">)</button>
                        <button data-append type="button">&lt;</button>
                        <button data-append type="button">&gt;</button>
                        <button data-append type="button">|a|</button>
                        <button data-append type="button">,</button>
                        <button data-append type="button">&le;</button>
                        <button data-append type="button">&ge;</button>
                        <button data-append type="button">&#8730;</button>
                        <button data-append type="button">&#960;</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Javascript:

```
  class Calculator {
  constructor(current_content) {
    this.current_content = current_content
    this.clear()
  }
  refresh() {
    this.currentOperand = this.current_content.innerText
  }

  clear() {
    this.currentOperand = ''
  }

  delete() {
    this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString().slice(0, -1)
  }

  appendNumber(number) {
    this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.toString()
  }

  appendPower2() {
    let str = '\u00B2'
    this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + str.toString()
  }

  tempPower(text) {
    let str = text
    str.style.cssText = 'font-size: xx-small; vertical-align: top;' 
    this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + str.toString()
  }

  appendPowers(tempower) {
    let str = '\u00B2' + tempower
    this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + str.toString()
  }

  updateDisplay() {
    this.current_content.innerText =
      this.currentOperand
  }
}

const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-append]')
const powerButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-powers]')
const powerButton2 = document.querySelectorAll('[data-power2]')
const equalsButton = document.querySelector('[data-equals]')
const deleteButton = document.querySelector('[data-delete]')
const allClearButton = document.querySelector('[data-all-clear]')
const current_content = document.querySelector('[data-current-content]')

const calculator = new Calculator(current_content)



numberButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calculator.refresh()
    calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)
    calculator.updateDisplay()
  })
})

powerButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (this.style.backgroundColor != 'yellow') {
      this.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'
    }
    else {
      this.style.backgroundColor = 'white'
    }
  })
});

powerButton2.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calculator.refresh()
    calculator.appendPower2()
    calculator.updateDisplay()
  })
})

allClearButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
  calculator.clear()
  calculator.updateDisplay()
})

deleteButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
  calculator.delete()
  calculator.updateDisplay()
})
```

Comment: That `while` loop at the end is likely to freeze the UI.  Also it's assigning yellow to backgroundColor, not checking for it.

Comment: yup, was just playing around with the while loop, its not working at the moment. I also do wish to change the color of the button while toggling. But essentially, I wish to apply the superscript function when the button is activated (yellow)